# [Android]How to get results from intent launched from preference screen?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I need help in geting results back from intent launched from 
preference screen

```
   // Intent preference 
   DevicePref = 
   getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this); 

   // Show a Screen with list of Devices Discovered 
   Intent i = new Intent(this,getDevice.class); 
   DevicePref.setIntent(i); 
   DevicePref.setTitle("Select Device"); 
   DevicePref.setSummary(mSelectedDevice); 
   deviceOptionsCat.addPreference(DevicePref);
```

I want user to select device... In preference screeen I show "Select 
Device" .. when user clicks that, another screen is launched by intent 
where all devices are listed. User selects the device.

Now how do I know user selected which device? And I want to update 
that in the summary.

Pls. let me know 
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I got the answer, Hope it will help someone like me...

Do not mention intent while creating preference like I did in above code.. Mention intent on OnPreferenceClickListener and then do StartActivityForResult()

```
    // Intent preference 
   DevicePref = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this); 
   // Show a Screen with list of Devices Discovered 

   DevicePref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(onPreferenceClick);

   DevicePref.setTitle("Select Device"); 
   DevicePref.setSummary(mSelectedDevice); 
   deviceOptionsCat.addPreference(DevicePref);
```

Then create OnPreferenceClickListner and here do StartActivityFromResult()

```
OnPreferenceClickListener onPreferenceClick = new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
       public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

           if (preference ==DevicePref )
           {
               Intent i = new Intent(DevuiceOptions.this,getDevice.class);  
               DevicePref.setIntent(i); 
               startActivityForResult(i,CHOOSE_DEVICE);

           }
           return true;
       }
   };
```

Finally to get the result handle onActivityResult and update Summary field.

```
@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
   {

       switch (requestCode) {

           case Constants.CHOOSE_DEVICE:
           {
               if (data!=null )
               {
                   Bundle b = data.getExtras();
                   mSelectedDevice =    (String) b.get("Name");
                   UpdatePreferences();
               }

           }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This Worked for me .. Thanks !  Initially , onActivityResult was being called only the second time . That was because onPreferenceClick was returning a false.